# Laravel relation using single table

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table with this migration schema,

```
Schema::create('pages', function(Blueprint $table) {
   $table->integer('id', true);
   $table->string('title');
   $table->string('slug');
   $table->string('layout');
   $table->text('body');
   $table->integer('parent_id');
   $table->integer('page_order');
   $table->enum('is_navigation', array('yes', 'no'))->default('yes');
   $table->timestamps();
   $table->softDeletes();
});
```

This table is used to save dynamic multi-level page details. If the page is a parent, the `parent_id` will be zero and if a page is under another page, it will have the parent page id as `parent_id`.Now I need to display the data in a table including parent title. My code is,

```
$table_prefix = DB::getTablePrefix();

$pages = DB::select(DB::raw("select A.*,B.title as parent from ".$table_prefix."pages as A left join ".$table_prefix."pages as B on A.parent_id = B.id where A.deleted_at is null"));
```

It's working fine but I can't use `paginate()` here.

How can I replace this query using eloquent relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paginate()` there. Take a look at the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination).

```
DB::table('pages')
    ->select("pages.*", "parent_pages.title as parent")
    ->leftJoin('pages as parent_pages', 'parent_pages.id = pages.parent_id')
    ->where('pages.deleted_at', '=', null)
    ->paginate(10);
```

You can also use the eloquent way to remove the trashed where clause as eloquent should handle that.

```
Page::where("pages.*", "parent_pages.title as parent")
    ->leftJoin('pages as parent_pages', 'parent_pages.id = pages.parent_id')
    ->paginate(10);
```

*Not tested, just re-factored the raw query string*

Comment: These query given me this error ``SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`` where `pages`.`deleted_at` is null and `pages`.* = ?' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `pages` left join `pages` as `parent_pages` on `cmsplus_parent_pages`.`id = pages`.`parent_id` `` where `pages`.`deleted_at` is null and `pages`.* = ?) (Bindings: array (
0 => 'parent_pages.title as parent',
))``

Comment: Try explicitly defining the SQL columns, this was not meant to be the final solution. Just letting you know that you can in fact use `paginate()` where you thought was not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper ORM method. First define the relationship in your model. Then eager load the relationship during your query. With eager loading this happens in two SQL queries. One for the list of pages and another for all the pages parents.

```
// In Page class

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Page', 'parent_id');
}

// Elsewhere

$pages = Page::with('parent')->paginate(10);

foreach ($pages as $page)
{
    if ($page->parent)
    {
        echo $page->parent->title;
    }

    echo $page->title;
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting ``results":{}`` with ``public function index() {

  $pages = Page::with('parent')->paginate($limit = 10);

        return Response::json(array(
         'status'  => 'success',
         'message' => 'Page successfully loaded!',
         'results'   => $pages),
         200
     );
}``

Comment: Isolate the issue. What happens if you dd($results)? What is DB actually returning? What happens if you use ->get() instead?